# ASP.NET MVC - custom error message based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am trying to create a custom error message based on a condition here. I have date field which is a conditional mandatory field. I want to make that required field based on some condition only.

I have created a method which checks those condition and if it fails then it inserts a error message into the `ModelState`.

Validator Class

```
public class Validator
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> errors { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; } = true;

    public Validator()
    {
        errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void PatientDetailRules(PatientDetailModel model)
    {
        //Rule 11 - Last sight test - requried on condition
        if (!model.IsFirstTest && !model.IsTestDateUnknow)
        {
            if (model.DateOfLastSight == DateTime.MinValue)
                errors.Add(nameof(model.DateOfLastSight), "missing");
        }
     }
}
```

PatientDetailModel.cs

```
public class PatientDetailModel
{
   [Display(Name = "OPH_GOS1_DateOfLastSight", ResourceType = typeof(Ophthalmic))]
    public DateTime DateOfLastSight { get; set; }

}
```

Controller - Action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitPatientDetails(PatientDetailModel Model)
    {
        Validator vs = new Validator();
        vs.PatientDetailRules(Model);
        if (!vs.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> errorlist in vs.errors)
                ModelState.AddModelError(errorlist.Key, errorlist.Value);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = Entities.Ophthalmic.DataAccess.SavePatientDetails(Model);
            return Json(new { result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return PartialView("~/views/Ophthalmic/Partials/_PatientDetails.cshtml", Model);
     }
```

view -

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="margin-top-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.DateOfLastSight)
        <div class="display-flex">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfLastSight, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", maxlength = 8, id = "txtLastSightTestDate" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfLastSight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But here, I am not sure why. Its giving the error as "The LAST SIGHT TEST DATE is requried." This message is coming from attribute "Data-val-required" which is generating in HTML. But i have not given as required field attribute here.

Also when I make datatype nullable, (Datetime?) in model the nits not giving any error itself.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT - I also tried inserting error from Resource file but still not working.

```
if (!model.IsFirstTest && !model.IsTestDateUnknow)
        {
            if (model.DateOfLastSight == DateTime.MinValue)
                errors.Add(nameof(model.DateOfLastSight), Resources.Ophthalmic.OPH_GOS1_DateOfLastSightMissingError);
        }
```

Comment: Your property is `DateTime` which is not nullable (i.e it is required). And you should be using a `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` to do your validation (so you get both client and server side validation. Refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried DateTime property making nullbale (DateTime?). Then its not showing any error message at all!

Comment: That would be becase of  `if (model.DateOfLastSight == DateTime.MinValue)` - (it would be `null`, not `DateTime.MinValue`) but its irrelevant anyway - this is not the right way to validate properties in a model. Read the link I gave you

Comment: No .. Its going inside the if loop and inserting key in error dictionary

Comment: But you never assign a value to `IsValid` so its `true` (again - do not do this!)